# How to pass an array to js button click in phalcon volt template engine

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I am passing an associative array from my controller to my view and then iterating it on the template engine

```
 <tbody class="text-center">
                        {% for inv in inv_list %}
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="{{ inv['supplier_invoice_number'] }}"></td>
                                <td>{{ inv['contract_id'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ inv['supplier_invoice_number'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ inv['final_payable_amount'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ inv['markup_value'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ inv['markup_type'] }}</td>
                                <td>{{ inv['buyer_price'] }}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="generateInvoice('{{ inv }}')">Invoice</button></td>
                                
                                <td><button class="btn btn-success">Invoice Email</button></td>

                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
```

Like above .I want to pass the value of the object in the onclick method ,but its giving an error

> Array to string conversion

.How to solve this .Please help me out

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You are much more likely to receive help from others if your provide well formatted and human readable code to others. Could you take a moment and update the indentation of your code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Error `Array to string conversion`means tat you try to print an array. In your case `inv`is an array. I think that you need only to pass the id like  `onclick="generateInvoice('{{ inv['contract_id'] }}')"` or a other unique value from your inc array.

Comment: I need all the values in inv in my function how to pass them ?

Comment: @technogeek multiple ways to do that. 1) `implode()` 2) make a json string (`json_encode()`). an di think a json would for you good

Comment: `{{implode(inv)}}` is not working

Comment: That could not work. i dont know how you can use php functions in the view in volt but in the controller you can convert your inv to a new seperate var with json_encode($inc) and save them in your inv object by a new key (like myJson). then you can can access in your view by this key like : `{{ inc['myJson']`. that was it!